# Android gmail app

Tags: applications, mobile-data

In micromax canvas, i am unable to find account settings in gmail app . I need to add recovery mobile number to my gmail account in my mobile ? how to do it in specified mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail app for android have no option to change your account settings. Instead you should add a phone number using a web browser. Inorder to [set up a recovery mobile number or email address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/183723?hl=en):

> 1. Sign in to your [gmail account](https://myaccount.google.com/).
> 2. In the "Personal info & privacy" section, select "Your personal info".
> 3. Choose "Phone".
> 4. If adding a phone number, select "Add Recovery Phone".
>      Or, if editing a phone number, select edit [image: Edit_Pencil_img].
> 5. Follow the onscreen instructions.
>
> *Note: You must use a mobile phone with text messaging turned on.*

Comment: I need to do it in  my micromax canvas set

Comment: Navigate to the [https://myaccount.google.com](https://myaccount.google.com) section of your google account with your mobile web browser of your micromax canvas.

Comment: its not working ,its asking for login password in browser. i dont know my password, that is why i need to add recovery mobile number.Is there any solution?